# Robguice proguard forces

Tags: android, proguard, roboguice

This is the bare minimum specified by Roboguice for proguard support: https://gist.github.com/matthawley/1327908

I am forced to add these to prevent the code from crashing:

```
-keep class com.appmanager.ui.fragments.* { *; }
-keep class com.appmanager.ui.views.* { *; }
```

Which means that all of my views and fragments are not obfuscated. Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big expert of `progurad`. But according to [documentation](http://I'm%20not%20big%20expert%20about%20proguard.%20According%20to%20http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) you can ask `proguard` keep only annotated fields.

I've just checked the official `RoboGuice` [wiki](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/ProGuard) for `proguard` and it is saying that it only requires field names, activity names, services names, some specific method names, etc.

I'm not sure how big is you project and how wide `RoboGuice` is used. You can try another dependency injection like `Dagger` which uses much less reflection (version 2.0 is free from reflection at all)